# Java - Convert boolean[] to decimal

Tags: java, boolean, decimal

A boolean array can be considered to be a binary number e.g.

```
boolean[] four = {true, false, false}; //100
```

I would like to convert such an array to its decimal equivalent e.g.

```
int decimal = convertBooleanArrayToDecimal(four);
//decimal == 4
```

How can I do so?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
long result = 0;
for (boolean bit : four) {
    result = result * 2 + (bit ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Please review that expression! I believe you're multiplying by (2 + bit) rather than adding bit and multiplying by 2.

Comment: @Carl:  I'm pretty sure the multiplication takes precedence.  But a pair of parens to clarify/ensure it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @BlairHippo there was a mistake initially, but I corrected it in few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution:

```
long result = 0;
for (boolean bit: boolArray)
{
    result <<= 1;
    if (bit) result += 1;
}
```

This is mathematically equivalent to Nikita's solution, but I find the bit-shifting version to be clearer.